# Using rolling function for DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a function like rollapply for data.frame [duplicate]
[R rolling equation on data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289791/r-rolling-equation-on-data-frame?rq=1)

R rolling equation on data.frame
[Is there a function like rollapply for data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771385/is-there-a-function-like-rollapply-for-data-frame)

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-0/topics/rollapply

===========================================================================
I want to make column named '3mean' contains last 3 periods mean price.

As you know, python pandas offers `roll_sum`, `roll_mean` function for DataFrame. But I can't find such thing in R.

I have read `rollapply` function example·question but that is not a dataframe thing or I could not understand because of the complexity.

How can I make a `3mean` column?

Thank you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
today <- Sys.Date()
kq <- getSymbols("^kq11", 
             from = today-30, 
             to = today, 
             auto.assign = F)

head(kq,15)



> head(kq,15)
       KQ11.Open KQ11.High KQ11.Low KQ11.Close
2017-06-19    672.72    675.71   672.25     675.44
2017-06-20    678.72    678.82   669.41     669.41
2017-06-21    668.41    668.44   662.68     665.77
2017-06-22    667.99    668.36   663.26     663.28
2017-06-23    665.19    669.05   665.02     668.93
2017-06-26    670.59    670.78   667.71     668.36
2017-06-27    671.70    673.13   670.87     672.63
2017-06-28    671.26    672.36   665.89     665.89
2017-06-29    670.10    670.56   666.00     668.00
2017-06-30    665.67    669.12   665.57     669.04
2017-07-03    671.17    671.17   660.04     660.97
2017-07-04    662.17    663.85   654.06     656.19
```

Comment: Could you show example calculation for one example?

Comment: which price from OHLC do you want to use?

Comment: @AK88 I want to use 'KQ11.Close' column. Thank you.

Comment: @RonakShah ex) 3mean = (675.44+669.41+665.77)/3  / dataframe like NA,NA, 670.20,……   . Thank you.

Comment: `rollmean(kq$KQ11.Close, 3, align = "right", fill = NA)` Or `rollmeanr(kq$KQ11.Close, 3, fill = NA)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Fantastic. Thanks for the advice. I solve the problem. I could not know rollmean function before. I don't know what's the different. I think rollmean.

Comment: @RonakShah Please, write a same answer in answer thing to see rookie like me.

Comment: @Jabda100su Actually, this has been asked before, so just linking that. :)